# how to give encoding as ISO-8859-1 in xml created using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-encoding

I have to create an xml file which has encoding as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Currently the xml I am creating using LINQ is having tag as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

how can I do this using LINQ only.

Comment: Linq is to do queries, not to write XML. So, as you ask for a "Linq only" method to do it, the answer is: There is no way to do it.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: I believe this question is about _LINQ to XML_ which indeed can be used to write XML, and I have changed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `XDeclaration`:

```
var d = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", ""), new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
    new XElement("Child2", "data2")
 ));
```

Comment: Interestingly, this does indeed work with `XDocument.Save(fileName)` which must infer the encoding to use if an `XDeclaration` is present.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the `XDocument` to a `StreamWriter` having the desired encoding:

```
var xDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("root"));
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
using (var fileStream = File.Create("... file name ..."))
  using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, encoding))
    xDocument.Save(streamWriter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XMLDcoument, then you can do so like below:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", null);
        doc.AppendChild(declaration);
        var node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Root", "");
        doc.AppendChild(node);
        doc.Save("TestDoc.xml");
```